Is my concept for Writhing Ones viable?
My idea for an ent-like species is as follows.
The Writhing Ones are a race of giant eusocial nematodes. They evolved to collaborate for the benefit of the collective and over time, colonies grew into an emergent consciousness of bud-tenders.
They began as a water-dwelling species of mangrove-tenders, shaping the roots of the trees to trap fish, where the nematodes could ensnare and consume them, or use them as lures.
However, the mangroves they called home began to dry out, and they were forced to find a way to survive, or die. Some grew vines in the shape of crab carapaces and lived within them, sealing them with mucus and controlling the other bud-worms with pheromones to move.
They have since abandoned such primitive vessels, instead adopting a great variety of materials such as bark, moss, wood, and metal.
Elders do not use vessels, instead rooting down into the ground once they have become too large and serving as a nursery for the bud-tenders that they will produce at this stage.
Buds refer to developing young that bud off of the queen, who is about as large as a human head.
Bud-tenders refer to the nematodes that care for the young buds and make up the majority of the body.
Before the queen dies she will produce queen-buds that use the last of her strength to either take control of her body, or venture out with a fraction of the workers.
Males exist but they are rare, and do not reproduce by budding, instead only reproducing when cut in half.
Let me know of any alterations to make to this concept.
EDIT: I need help with fleshing them out and justifying a transition between obligate and facultative sapience (fish-traps and primitive agriculture to vessels and so on). Furthermore if this concept is not feasible (too unrealistic) I would like an alternative to this concept.

What is the specific world building issue you have with your creations? "Is X viable" isn't really good question, because the constraints on viability lie entirely within the world you're creating.

@StarfishPrime i mean would it be scientifically plausible.

Maximum of 1 cm long or more like 200 km long? Depends on a lot of things in the environment and the creatures themselves, you've not told us all that much about them. Could you also tell us about their environment, give us a bit about the planet too. What do they eat, what eats them?

it is not completely improbable, but there are some issues:

nematodes are borderline brainless. There needs to be some evolutionary pressure for them to develop rudimentary intelligence prior to them becoming hive-species.
nematodes are slow. I assume your Writhing Ones move by masses of nematodes contracting, which will make them even slower than "fantasy" Writhing Ones.
what do they eat? Underwater mangrove nematodes could trap fish and insects, but land based Writhing Ones would either need to rapidly become absolute omnivores, or become extremely good at hunting, because there is just not enough protein on land for them to eat. Ants, bees, wasps and other hive-creatures solve it by sending scouting parties to gather food, can your Writhing Ones do the same?
are the Writhing Ones-nematodes edible? The way you describe them would make them a walking buffet for any land based creature, from worm-eating birds to wandering bears, and definitely humans. If the Writhing Ones armor is made of mucus and plant matter, then a bear, a wild pig, a badger or even a woodpecker would just crack it open and gorge itself on the nematodes with near-impunity. A group of humans with axes, shovels and buckets could turn a Writhing One into a ton of wormy protein and kindling, with nearly no effort or danger to themselves. Make the worms poisonous to give them a fighting chance.


Good point. The nematodes I am basing these ents off of will be about the same size as hagfish. Additionally, the queen is the brain, and secretes pheromones to command her workers.

Lastly, you make a good point with the armor materials. The mucus is poisonous (it is extremely rich in neurotoxins) and the workers are vicious regardless of if they are stripping bark from trees or flesh from bone. The mucus is more of a rapidly hardening tube that they excrete and pull themselves through. With each use they layer and grow harder.

One more thing about movement, I was thinking maybe they could move like a swarm of army ants, or raft similarly to fire ants.
